# How do I filter an object with an object using Array.filter similar to lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-modules

I am trying to avoid importing lodash for a simple filter. I am trying to do something similar to this...

```
// Items
[
  { "title": "a", "name": "a", "location": "here"},
  { "title": "b", "name": "a", "location": "here"}, 
  { "title": "d", "location": "there"}, 
]
// Filter
{ "name" : "a", "location": "here" }
```

Should return the first two items. In lodash this is done by something similar to `_.filter(Items, Filter)`. I would like to implement this without lodash or a bunch of code and getting `Object.keys`. Is there a simple way in modern Javascript to handle this?

Comment: I tried searching but if this was already asked in a diff way let me know and I will delete.

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/filter.js

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with, seems to work well

```js
let foo = [
  { "title": "a", "name": "a", "location": "here"},
  { "title": "b", "name": "a", "location": "here"}, 
  { "title": "d", "location": "there"}, 
];

let bar = { "name" : "a", "location": "here" };

let result = foo.filter(obj =>
  Object.entries(bar).every(([k,v]) => obj[k]===v)
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You beat me to it by a couple of minutes.  Good answer.  Though I'd add a little more whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a "simple way in modern Javascript to handle this" but if you don't have a hard requirement on avoiding `Object.keys` you could write a helper function to do this:

```js
const myItems = [
  { "title": "a", "name": "a", "location": "here"},
  { "title": "b", "name": "a", "location": "here"}, 
  { "title": "d", "location": "there"}, 
]

const myFilter = { "name" : "a", "location": "here" };

const filter = (items, filterBy) => 
  items.filter(item => 
    Object.keys(filterBy).every(key => item[key] === filterBy[key])
  )

alert(JSON.stringify(filter(myItems, myFilter)));
```

Comment: we wrote basically identical solutions lol, didn't see yours until I refreshed the page

Answer (score 0):

You could get the entries of the filter in advance to prevent getting th entries for every filtering iteration.

```js
const
    filter = (array, filter) => {
        const
            filterBy = entries => o => entries.every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v);

        return items.filter(filterBy(Object.entries(filters)));
    },
    items = [{ title: "a", name: "a", location: "here" }, { title: "b", name: "a", location: "here" }, { title: "d", location: "there"}],
    filters = { name: "a", location: "here" },
    result = filter(items, filters);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```